# Vuejs not working via Mobile Browser

Tags: laravel, vue-resource, vue.js

I have this [betting app](http://shindabet.co.ke/) developed I have developed using Vuejs and Laravel. Everything works on my PC but when I try to open the link via my iPad or iPhone, it dispalys as if Vuejs is not loaded. Here is my [VueJs code](http://shindabet.co.ke/js/shindabet.js) Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: What's exactly wrong? Can you provide some screenshots? What version of iOS / Safari Mobile are you testing it on? It seems fine on my iDevices.

Comment: @DanM. Here is the [screenshot](http://imgur.com/qQJdHju) as seen my iPad. I am using the latest versions of Chrome/Safari

Comment: What if you switch to a private window and try it there? Still works fine for me, can't get it to break. Makes me wonder if it's not a cache issue. Are you developing on a Mac btw?

Comment: I am developing on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that JS is enabled on your device. if not you can enable it via your safari settings in your settings menu.

Comment: JS is enabled already because I can open websites that uses Vuejs on my iDevices.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. There was a function I wrote like this.

```js
function(g=null) {
    if(g){
        //
    } else {
        //
    }
}
```

I guess this is not allowed in Javascript. I used that in PHP a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(g=null) {
    if(g){
        //
    } else {
        //
    }
}
```

condition in function?

better

```
function() {
    let g = null
    if(g == null){
        //
    } else {
        //
    }
}
```